# Prometheus OR when using rate()

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, prometheus, promql

**Summary**

I'm trying to figure out how to properly use the OR `|` operator in a Prometheus query because my imported Grafana dashboard is not working.

**Long version**

I'm trying to debug a Grafana dashboard based on some data scraped from my Kubernetes pods running [AppMetrics/Prometheus](https://github.com/AppMetrics/Prometheus); the dashboard is [here](https://grafana.com/dashboards/2204). Basically what happens is that when the value "All" for the `server` is selected on the Grafana dashboard (`server` is an individual pod in this case), no data appears. However, when I select an individual pod, then data does appear.

Here's an example of the same metric scraped from the two pods:

```
# HELP application_httprequests_transactions 
# TYPE application_httprequests_transactions summary
application_httprequests_transactions_sum{server="myapp-test-58d94bf78d-jdq78",app="MyApp",env="test"} 5.006965628
application_httprequests_transactions_count{server="myapp-test-58d94bf78d-jdq78",app="MyApp",env="test"} 1367
application_httprequests_transactions{server="myapp-test-58d94bf78d-jdq78",app="MyApp",env="test",quantile="0.5"} 0.000202825
application_httprequests_transactions{server="myapp-test-58d94bf78d-jdq78",app="MyApp",env="test",quantile="0.75"} 0.000279318
application_httprequests_transactions{server="myapp-test-58d94bf78d-jdq78",app="MyApp",env="test",quantile="0.95"} 0.000329862
application_httprequests_transactions{server="myapp-test-58d94bf78d-jdq78",app="MyApp",env="test",quantile="0.99"} 0.055584233

# HELP application_httprequests_transactions 
# TYPE application_httprequests_transactions summary
application_httprequests_transactions_sum{server="myapp-test-58d94bf78d-l9tdv",app="MyApp",env="test"} 6.10214788
application_httprequests_transactions_count{server="myapp-test-58d94bf78d-l9tdv",app="MyApp",env="test"} 1363
application_httprequests_transactions{server="myapp-test-58d94bf78d-l9tdv",app="MyApp",env="test",quantile="0.5"} 0.000218548
application_httprequests_transactions{server="myapp-test-58d94bf78d-l9tdv",app="MyApp",env="test",quantile="0.75"} 0.000277483
application_httprequests_transactions{server="myapp-test-58d94bf78d-l9tdv",app="MyApp",env="test",quantile="0.95"} 0.033821094
application_httprequests_transactions{server="myapp-test-58d94bf78d-l9tdv",app="MyApp",env="test",quantile="0.99"} 0.097113234
```

I ran the Query inspector in Grafana to find out which query it is calling, and then ran the PromQL query in Prometheus itself. Basically, when I execute the following PromQL queries individually, they return data:

```
rate(application_httprequests_transactions_count{env="test",app="MyApp",server="myapp-test-58d94bf78d-l9tdv"}[15m])*60

rate(application_httprequests_transactions_count{env="test",app="MyApp",server="myapp-test-58d94bf78d-jdq78"}[15m])*60
```

However, when I try to use PromQL's `|` operator to combine them, I don't get data back:

```
rate(application_httprequests_transactions_count{env="test",app="MyApp",server="myapp-test-58d94bf78d-l9tdv|myapp-test-58d94bf78d-jdq78"}[15m])*60
```

Here's the raw output from Grafana's query inspector:

```
xhrStatus:"complete"

request:Object

method:"GET"
url:"api/datasources/proxy/56/api/v1/query_range?query=rate(application_httprequests_transactions_count%7Benv%3D%22test%22%2Capp%3D%22MyApp%22%2Cserver%3D%22myapp-test-58d94bf78d-jdq78%7Cmyapp-test-58d94bf78d-l9tdv%7Cmyapp-test-5b8c9845fb-7lklm%7Cmyapp-test-5b8c9845fb-8jf7n%7Cmyapp-test-5b8c9845fb-d9x5c%7Cmyapp-test-5b8c9845fb-fw4gj%7Cmyapp-test-5b8c9845fb-vtl9z%7Cmyapp-test-5b8c9845fb-vv7xv%7Cmyapp-test-5b8c9845fb-wq9bs%7Cmyapp-test-5b8c9845fb-xqfrt%7Cmyapp-test-69999d58b5-549vd%7Cmyapp-test-69999d58b5-lmp8x%7Cmyapp-test-69999d58b5-nbvt9%7Cmyapp-test-69999d58b5-qphj2%7Cmyapp-test-6b8dcc5ffb-gjjvj%7Cmyapp-test-6b8dcc5ffb-rxfk2%7Cmyapp-test-7fdf446767-bzhm2%7Cmyapp-test-7fdf446767-hp46w%7Cmyapp-test-7fdf446767-rhqhq%7Cmyapp-test-7fdf446767-wxmm2%22%7D%5B1m%5D)*60&start=1540574190&end=1540574505&step=15"

response:Object

status:"success"

data:Object

resultType:"matrix"

result:Array[0] => []
```

I opened a GitHub issue for this as well; it has a quick GIF screen recording showing what I mean: [AppMetrics/Prometheus#43](https://github.com/AppMetrics/Prometheus/issues/43)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`|` is for regular expressions, PromQL doesn't have a `|` operator (but it does have an `or` operator). You need to specify that the matcher is a regex rather than an exact match with `=~`:

```
rate(application_httprequest_transactions_count{env="test",app="MyApp",server=~"myapp-test-58d94bf78d-l9tdv|myapp-test-58d94bf78d-jdq78"}[15m])*60
```